# Filter Nsarray of coredata objects which have not same value for two differnt attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have core data with properties named `productId` & `usedProductId` i want to get all data in which both have different values

I used following predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productId != usedProductId"]
```

its work fine if both have some values but its not returning those results in which `usedProductId = nil` & productId has some value.

To overcome this i used `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productId != usedProductId" OR (usedProductId == NIL AND productId.length > 0)]` but its not efficient solution i guess it should possible without OR condition.

I am not good explainer so please feel free to ask for any more explanations of questions. :)

Comment: Did you try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(productId == usedProductId)"] `?

Comment: tried that too. its return same result as `productId != usedProductId`

Comment: OR it's basic compound predicate. Its normal to use that solution.
Check official Apple guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Is your context backed by an in-memory store or SQL?

Comment: I used coredata.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474058/coredata-fetchrequest-with-predicate-incorrectly-skips-null-values Seems there is no other way around.